# Javascript - Is there a more efficient method to repeat rectangle creation?

Tags: javascript, canvas

So i have this relatively simple code:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(400 * Math.random(), 400 * Math.random(), 3, 3);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

Essentially it just creates a black canvas then randomly places a yellow square on it. Other than mindlessly copy and pasting, is there a more efficient method to redraw this multiple times? (Maybe some kind of `setTimeout` function?)

Comment: store it in a function and invoke the function inside setTimeout.

Comment: Put it in a function, call the function inside a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you out.

```js
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function(){callRect();}, 3000);
}
function callRect(){
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
ctx.fillRect(400 * Math.random(), 400 * Math.random(), 3, 3);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inspiration</title>
    
</head>
<body>
<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
<button type='button' onclick='myFunction();'>Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah that's great,upvote too if it helps you out. :)